# Azure search doesn't distinguish between singular and plural

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure search and in my indexed database table I have a row with the text 'Government Grants'.

When i search 'Grant' it returns no results, If I search 'Grants' it returns results

I have the same issue with 'Sales' and 'Sale'

How can I configure azure search so that it matches singular and plural words?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check that corresponding field in your search index is set to be searchable, and that a natural language analyzer (such as "en.lucene" or "en.microsoft") is selected as the analyzer for that field. The default analyzer, "standard", doesn't handle plural forms or any other word inflections, because it doesn't do any linguistic processing.

HTH,
Eugene